# how to list out items from android market for in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I am making an Android app based on in app purchase. In my app I have a sample video and if a user wants to buy it, I want to make an in app purchase through Android Market site.

I went through the steps in [Downloading the Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download).

I downloaded the sample app and I tried to use it for checking purpose. I added my public key of my market account and added the video name I have to show to the user. In my market account, in the in app product list I added the details of my video title, description, product id.

In the developer site I found the following line:

> Do not publish the sample application; leave it as an unpublished draft application. 
>   The sample application is for demonstration purposes only and should not be made publicly available on Android Market.

When I run the app and click the buy button an alert box gets appeared saying that 
"The Item that you requested is not available for purchase".

Comment: my android market account is not a gmail id and in my android market profile i have added my gmail account as the test account. In my device i have signed in using my gmail account - is this the reason for my problem......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

at last i found my mistake with the help of a sample app. The in app product id which is given in the market account must be given in two places of the app. In the 
`CatalogEntry[] CATALOG and in the strings.xml file the ids entered must be the same.` i have given the same id in Catalog entry but not in the strings.xml file

now the in app products gets listed out correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The Android documentation is quite confusing on this point.

Yes, leave the APK as draft--do not publish it.

Make sure the email address attached to your device is entered in the "Test Accounts" field (separate multiple email addresses with commas): https://market.android.com/publish/editProfile

However, when you add an in-app purchase product to the app, you need to click the publish button ON THAT PRODUCT. The app is not published, but the product is.

If you do this, then you should be able to run the app on your device, view the IAP products and purchase one, but other people would not be able to, if their email address was not listed in the Test Accounts for your developer profile.